# POSTGRESQL 9.6 COPY created file bigger than the table

Tags: postgresql, copy, oracle-fdw

Im trying to export oracle table into a local postgresql dump via the copy command :

```
\copy (select * from remote_oracle_table) to /postgresql/table.dump with binary;
```

The oracle table`s size is 25G. Howvere, the copy command created a 50G file. How is it possible ?

I'm capable of selecting from remote oracle table because i have the oracle_fdw 
extension.

Comment: text is kept in compressed storage in Postgres (TOAST). I don't remember the Oracle datafile structure, but I'm quite positive Oracle optimises text storage as well, thus it should be expected that text file takes more space then text column. what are the datatypes in your table?

Comment: But as you can see in the command I used i chose a binary format. The datatypes are date,integer,number,varchar2. Moreover I have 30 columns.

Comment: I don't think binary here is comparable to TOAST... Lets wait though - maybe somebody with knowledge of the source code will explain

Answer (score 1):

A few factors are likely at work here, including:

- Small numbers in `integer` and `numeric` fields use more space in binary format than text format;
- Oracle probably stores the table with some degree of compression, which the binary dump won't have.

You'll likely find that if you compress the resulting dump it'll be  a *lot* smaller.

Comment: If the `COPY` output is correct, this must be the explanation. As far as I know, Oracle compresses data by storing a value only once per table block and referencing it from other occurrences of the same value.